Trying to include \4 (any numeric values between 0 to 9) in regular expressions in ESAPI.properties, but its throwing an error as not a valid regex
Regex value defined in ESAPI.properties of HTTPParameterValue given below:
Validator.HTTPParameterName=^\[\\u0080-\\uFFFFa-zA-Z0-9.,;?!:%'\\\\p{L}$\\\\-"\<\>\~\\\\\[\\\\\]\`\\\\^#&()\\\\n\\\\t\\\\r\*/+=@\_}{|\\\\\\\\ \]\*$

Validator.HTTPParameterValue=^\[\\u0080-\\uFFFFa-zA-Z0-9.,;?!:%'\\\\p{L}$\\\\-"\<\>\~\\\\\[\\\\\]\`\\\\^#&()\\\\n\\\\t\\\\r\*/+=@\_}{|\\\\\\\\ \]\*$

when I try to input this value "3Y....1000.....24\0AB123456", this \\0 is consider as special character and throwing invalid input error from the given regex. But the same was working fine when I use esapi 2.2.0.0 jar. This issue is occurring in latest esapi jar from 2.4.0.0 only.
Getting below error in the console:
WARNING \[IntrusionDetector\] \[SECURITY FAILURE Anonymous:null@unknown -\> /IntrusionDetector\] Invalid input: context=HTTP parameter name: transactionId, type(HTTPParameterValue) \[input=**3Y....1000.....24AB123456**: org.owasp.esapi.errors.ValidationException: HTTP parameter name: transactionId: Invalid input. \]Please conform to regex

Tried some of regex pattern like /\\b(\[0-9\]|10)\\b /, \\d but doesn't worked. How to resolve this error.
Is there any validation has been included in latest esapi jar or any dependencies am i missing out?

Does this help? java, regular expression, need to escape backslash in regex Also, learn to use markdown to format your posts.

As an ESAPI library maintainer, be careful when editing the default regex values.  I would test your regex with the official codebase, noting if any unit tests fail.  You might configure this to be too permissive and end up with problems later.  Otherwise https://regex101.com/ to test and debug your java regex.

See my reply in the "Answer" section below. It is not really an answer per se, but I couldn't it to make it readable for a comment. My question though, is where did these values come from and why are you using them?

These look like custom regular expressions to me.
You mentioned this worked with release 2.2.0.0 and failed in 2.4.0.0, but for these 2 properties, only Validator.HTTPParameterValue changed, and its change was minor:
For 2.2.0.0: Validator.HTTPParameterValue=^[\p{L}\p{N}.\-/+=_ !$*?@]{0,1000}$
For 2.4.0.0:  Validator.HTTPParameterValue=^[-\p{L}\p{N}./+=_ !$*?@]{0,1000}$
In other words, the only change was that a '-' was permitted in the parameter name. (A change that was made in commit https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/commit/b7e9a55e3614d6a471ee531d4107652c5952678b.)
Just in case, I checked release 2.5.4.0, and these are not even values for the latest 2.5.4.0 release.
Also note, between 2.2.0.0 and 2.5.4.0 (the current release as of this writing), the value for Validator.HTTPParameterName stayed the same.
